# mod rewrite rule to replace + with -

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite rule which replaces underscores with hyphens:

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*) $1-$2 [N]

RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

This rule is great because it will check recursively so it turns `/word1_word2/` into `/word1-word2/`

But also works for `/word1_word2_word3_word4/` into `/word1-word2-word3-word4/`

**How can I modify this to replace the + symbol with a - (hyphen)?**

So that `/word1+word2/` turns into `/word1-word2/`

and

`/word1+word2+word3+word4/` turns into `/word1-word2-word3-word4/`

I've tried a dozen variations and cant seem to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the character everywhere where you have an underscore:

```
RewriteRule ^([^_+]*)[_+]([^_+]*[_+].*) $1-$2 [N]

RewriteRule ^([^_+]*)[_+]([^_+]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```